# Закруглённое imageview в Android

Tags: android, java, изображения

Суть проблемы следующая.
У меня имеется, отдельный java, в котором происходит округление получаемой картинки. Всё работает идеально. Но мне нужно сделать, чтобы не округляло, а делало фактически прямоугольник (или квадрат) с закруглёнными углами. Помогите, пожалуйста, переделать данный код:

```
public class RoundImageView extends ImageView {

    public RoundImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public RoundImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public RoundImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
        if (drawable == null) {
            return;
        }
        if (getWidth() == 0 || getHeight() == 0) {
            return;
        }
        Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
        Bitmap bitmap = b.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
        int w = getWidth(), h = getHeight();
        Bitmap roundBitmap = getCroppedBitmap(bitmap, w);
        canvas.drawBitmap(roundBitmap, 0, 0, null);
    }

    public static Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bmp, int radius) {
        Bitmap sbmp;
        if (bmp.getWidth() != radius || bmp.getHeight() != radius) {
            int size = bmp.getWidth() > bmp.getHeight() ? bmp.getHeight() : bmp.getWidth();
            Bitmap square = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, size, size);
            sbmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(square, radius, radius, false);
        } else {
            sbmp = bmp;
        }
        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(sbmp.getWidth(),
                sbmp.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, sbmp.getWidth(), sbmp.getHeight());

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
        paint.setDither(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        canvas.drawCircle(sbmp.getWidth() / 2 + 0.7f, sbmp.getHeight() / 2 + 0.7f,
                sbmp.getWidth() / 2 + 0.1f, paint);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(sbmp, rect, rect, paint);
        return output;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [RoundedImageView](https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView)